# Is this even something a human can understand

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, directory

You know I learned programming its basics I have 4 years of experience and what this code does not make any sense to me can anyone explain to me like 5 year old, what this code does I am trying to traverse through nested folders

c:\Users\Welcome\Desktop\Dlang\test1\test2\test3\test4

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

let dir = __dirname;

let iterate = function(dir) {
  const stack = [dir];

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let currentDir = stack.pop();

    fs.readdirSync(currentDir).forEach((item) => {
      let fullPath = path.join(currentDir, item);

      if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
        console.log(fullPath); // Output the directory path
        stack.push(fullPath);   // Push subdirectories onto the stack
      } else {
        console.log(fullPath); // Output the file path
      }
    });
  }
};

iterate(dir);
```

```
// expected test1/test2/test3/tes4
```

Comment: Why don't you add a bunch of `console.log()` statements and run it yourself? It's not really very complicated.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a big box of toys (the folders) and each toy box can have more toy boxes inside it (the subfolders). You want to find all the toy boxes (folders) and the toys inside them (files).
Here's what the code does:

1. First, it imports the necessary libraries: `fs` for file system operations and `path` for path manipulation.
2. Then, it sets the starting point (the current directory) as the `dir` variable.
3. The `iterate` function is defined. This function will be used to traverse through all the toy boxes (folders) and their sub-toy boxes (subfolders).
4. Inside the `iterate` function, it creates a stack (an array-like data structure) and adds the starting point (the current directory) to it.
5. Then, it enters a while loop that continues until the stack is empty. Inside the loop, it removes the top toy box (folder) from the stack and processes it.
6. If the current toy box (folder) is a directory (i.e., it has more toy boxes inside it), it adds it to the stack. This way, the program will eventually explore all the subdirectories.
7. If the current toy box (folder) is a file (i.e., it doesn't have any toy boxes inside it), it simply outputs the file path.
8. Finally, the `iterate` function is called with the starting point (the current directory) as its argument.

This code will output the paths of all the folders and files in the specified directory and its subdirectories.

I hope this helps you understand the code better! Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

This code will traverse the directory by doing a for loop on the current directory. If it's a file, then alright we found one. If it's a directory we should traverse it - later. In the meantime we will schedule it by pushing it to the queue of directories to scan. This is called BFS because it will first finish current directory before moving on to next one.

Maybe, probably not, a recursion would demonstrate the idea further.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

let dir = __dirname;

let iterate = function(currentDir) {

  fs.readdirSync(currentDir).forEach((item) => {
    let fullPath = path.join(currentDir, item);

    if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
      console.log(fullPath); // Output the directory path
      iterate(fullPath)
    } else {
      console.log(fullPath); // Output the file path
    }
  });

};

iterate(dir);
```

This one, though, will go "deep" as soon as it finds a directory, therefore this way of traversing is called DFS.

Both codes haven't been tested by me, but they look they might work in traversing all entries of a directory and its subs.